# Vercel deployment under a folder

Tags: vercel

Is it possible to deploy a linked Git branch to vercel at a custom folder `www.abc.com/customFolderA/customFolderB`.

Also, `www.abc.com/customFolderC` is an existing deployment which i don't want to touch.